# MindSqualls - can I connect more than one NXT brick using USB?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt

To access my NXT brick connected via USB with the MindSqualls library, I do the following:

```
var brick = new McNxtBrick(NxtCommLinkType.USB, 0);
```

The 0 is serialPortNr. If I were to buy a second NXT kit, would it be possible to connect it in a similar way (e.g. by setting the second parameter to 1)? Or can only one brick be connected at a time?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had a quick look through the MindSqualls code and it looks like you can. I cannot test this however as I don’t have two kits.

Note: I believe it is preferred to NxtBrick class rather than McNxtBrick class as the latter is for a special program used for precise control over the NXT motors.